# protobuf unmarshal error in scala, throw a com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException

Tags: scala, go, protocol-buffers

in client(golang), i use protobuf to marshal a message into byte array, in server(scala), i use same proto  `parseFrom` this byte array, get an error:

com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field.  This could mean either that the input has been truncated or that an embedded message misreported its own length.

Comment: in client(golang), use concurrent programming, this stage proto is only read, not exist writing, this error rate in server(scala) is 0.5%